# ngb-datepicker change tooltips language

Tags: angular, internationalization, ng-bootstrap, angular-i18n, ngb-datepicker

I've got a multi-language app which uses a custom `NgbDatePickerI18n`:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomDatepickerService extends NgbDatepickerI18n {

    constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
        super();
    }

    getWeekdayShortName(weekday: number): string {
        return I18N_VALUES[this.translateService.getLanguage()].weekdays[weekday - 1];
    }

    getMonthShortName(month: number): string {
        return I18N_VALUES[this.translateService.getLanguage()].months[month - 1];
    }

    getMonthFullName(month: number): string {
        return this.getMonthShortName(month);
    }

    getDayAriaLabel(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
        return `${date.day}-${date.month}-${date.year}`;
    }
}
```

all works fine however when I hover over the previous/next month button, and the drop downs to select the month/year I can see a little tooltip in English. I'd like to translate that. Looked at the actual code: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker-navigation.ts#L15 and the documentation https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#i18n about internationalization, it is not very clear to me how to achieve that. I can see the following:

> The next/previous button labels can be translated using the standard Angular i18n mechanism. For example, previous month label is extracted under the ngb.datepicker.previous-month name.

But like I say, I can't find a little example of how to integrate that inside my `CustomDatepickerService`. Could anyone give me a little example about how to achieve this assuming it's possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer i18n Internalization Angular docs https://angular.io/guide/i18n#internationalization-i18n

Need to follow Custom Ids and create .xlf file with these below tags.

```
<trans-unit id="ngb.datepicker.previous-month" datatype="html">
  <source>Previous Month</source>
  <target state="new">Translated Text</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Then you need to hook this .xlf into ng build script.

Reference : https://medium.com/frontend-fun/angular-introduction-to-internationalization-i18n-28226a85e04e

https://angular-templates.io/tutorials/about/angular-internationalization-i18n-multi-language-app

Comment: Is it possible to get the application to use different files on the fly or is it something static. I say that mainly because I want to be able to change the language of it within the same app and looking at the examples it seems that it actually builds the application with the translations?

Comment: have you found a solution for dynamically change the tooltips?

Comment: Any update regarding this